# Positioning two horizontal divs in a dynamic way

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside a container:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="A">
        Test<br/>        
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>
        Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>
    </div>
    <div id="B"></div>
</div>
```

What I need is that 'B' stays at the bottom and has a fixed size (200px). 'A' should stay at the top and fill the rest of the space available. When I now resize the parent element 'B' should stay at 200px and 'A' should shrink.

I wasn't able to get this working with pure CSS but I would really prefer to have it in CSS only.

I've made a Fiddle containing a solution with jQuery but I want to avoid JavaScript for layouting whenever it's possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/t6B2e/

Comment: display:flex can be a fall back for jQuery, since flex is less supported by browsers than javascript/jQuery

Comment: I'm working on an enterprise application which has strong guidelines on which browsers to support and which not to support. So i can rely on the flex stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `display:flex;` but keep jQuery as fallback ... or CSS as fallback. Whatever here a **[basic example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EheBo/)**:

```css
body {background:black;color:white;}
#outer {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
html, body , #outer {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
 #a {
   overflow:auto;
 }
#b {
  background:blue;
  min-height: 200px; /* you can use flex:1; to size it too */
}
```

**Important:** do not use Capital letter or numbers as first character naming ID or CLASS. it is not allowed and some browser will follow W3C recommendation. CSS can not be applied.

**To have one growing and the other shrink and overflow**, you can tune it with `flex:xx;`

Example where both div have a `min-height` and show scrollbar if needed. *The blue one has priority, the other one has a min-height too, so content can still be readable*

**[Example Here](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/hjvcL/)**.

```css
body {background:black;color:white;}
#outer {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
html, body , #outer {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
#a, #b {
  min-height: 100px; /* don't give a min-height to #a and it can shrink down to zero */
  overflow:auto;
}
 #a {
   flex:2;
 }
#b {
  background:blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the "flex" hint. It seems to be some kind of holy grail for all the css pain i had before. And the cool thing is the lowest ie version i have to support is ie10. So this will help with so many things.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the other answers, you could use the [`calc()` CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
#A{ 
    height: calc( 100% - 200px );
    width: 100%;
    background: #cccccc;
    overflow: auto;
}
#B{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

- [**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6B2e/6/)
- [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) is rather good

Comment: +1 interesting alternative, didn't know about calc before so good to learn something new

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, then all you need to do is change your `#A` css.

Complete example:

```
#A{ 
    position: absolute;
    bottom:200px;
    top: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #cccccc;
    overflow: auto;
}

#B{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

Basically, I removed the `height` and added the `bottom:200px` which forces the bottom of the element to always be 200px from the bottom of the parent.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/t6B2e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole outer area to scroll you can do it this way with minimal CSS http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/mvoaw/

```
#outer {
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

#A {
}

#B {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```